# Can you restore a macOS Sonoma Time Machine Backup onto a fresh Ventura install?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, restore

I've upgraded my MacBook Pro 14" (2021) to the macOS Sonoma Beta, but I'd like to reset it to macOS Ventura. However, I've used the beta for over a month and there are a lot of files that have changed on my Mac. I have backups from before the upgrade and from after, and I just made a fresh backup. Is it possible to use Migration Assistant or another Apple tool to restore the latest backup onto a fresh install of macOS Ventura, if I reset the Mac and use Recovery Options for a fresh download of macOS Ventura's latest stable release?

Comment: No.  Things have not changed, you cannot restore a backup from a later OS to an earlier one.  This is why you don't run beta OS on production machines, as you have just discovered.

Comment: Thankfully not my production machine, I'd just like to get all my machines back on the same page.